# LEFT JOIN 3 tables with GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables: tblusers, tblproducts, and tbldailylog:

**tblusers**

```
UserID  UserName
------  --------
  1001  Mary
  1002  John
```

**tblproducts**

```
UserID  ProductKey  ProductName
------  ----------  ----------  
  1001  key1        p1
  1001  key2        p2
```

**tbldailylog**

```
UserID  ProductKey  Counter  Updated
------  ----------  -------  ----------
  1001  key1             10  2018-01-01
  1001  key1             15  2018-01-02
  1001  key2             50  2018-01-01
```

==========

Test1: LEFT JOIN 2 TABLES: tblusers and tblproducts

Query: `SELECT tblusers.UserID, tblusers.UserName, tblproducts.ProductKey FROM tblusers LEFT JOIN tblproducts ON tblusers.UserID = tblproducts.UserID GROUP BY tblusers.UserID`

Result:

```
UserID  UserName  ProductKey
------  --------  ----------
  1001  Mary      key1
  1001  Mary      key2
  1002  John
```

==========

Test2: GET THE TOTAL COUNTER OF EACH ProductKey

Query: `SELECT UserID, ProductKey, SUM(Counter) as Total FROM tbldailylog GROUP BY ProductKey`

Result:

```
UserID  ProductKey  Total
------  ----------  -----
  1001  key1           25
  1001  key2           50
```

==========

I would like to have the below end result, how do I combine the 3 tables together? The end result is sorted by SUM(Counter) DESC. I apologize for couldn't display table data in a nice format for easier viewing. Thank you for your help.

End Result:

```
UserID  UserName  ProductKey  Total  ProductName
------  --------  ----------  -----  ----------
  1001  Mary      key2           50  p2
  1001  Mary      key1           25  p1
  1002  John
```

Edit: Sorry for not making it clear in my original posting. I added "ProductName" column to "tblproducts" and the final result, so we have to use all 3 tables in the query because "ProductName" doesn't exist in "tblusers" and "tbldailylog". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks spencer7593 for reformatting the table in a nice format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try this -

```
select tu.userid,
       tu.UserName,
       tdl.ProductKey,
       tp.ProductName,
       sum(tdl.Counter) as Total
  from tblusers tu
  left join tbldailylog tdl
    on tu.userid = tdl.userid
  left join tblproducts tp
    on tu.userid = tp.userid
 group by tu.userid, tu.UserName, tdl.ProductKey, tp.ProductName
 order by sum(tdl.counter) desc
```

Comment: Thanks Jaydip for your answer. However, I added "ProductName" column to "tblproducts" and the end result so all 3 tables will need to be used in the query. Sorry for didn't make it clear.

Comment: You can use left join two join multiple tables too. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.UserID, u.UserName, l.ProductKey, p.ProductName SUM(l.Counter) as Total 
FROM tblUsers u
LEFT JOIN tbldailylog l ON l.UserID = u.UserID
LEFT JOIN tblProducts p ON p.UserID = t.UserID AND p.ProductKey = t.ProductKey
GROUP BY l.UserID, l.ProductKey, u.UserName, p.ProductName
```

Comment: I think with your query, you will miss "John" record because he doesn't have an entry in "tbldailylog".

Comment: @RachelSmiths Then you just need to `JOIN` it with `tblUsers`.

Comment: I think you are trying to be funny. I know I need to JOIN 3 tables together (I mentioned it in the title). However, I had some issues getting the right end result and that was why I posted the question here. Thank you for your help though :)

Comment: @RachelSmiths Not trying to be funny, but your main issue is on the `tbldailylog` table so that's what I fix in the query.  The other 2 tables are just simple joins to get the name.  But in case you want the full solution, I just updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle database this will work :    select t.UserID,t.UserName,tp.ProductKey,sum(tl.counter) total from TBLUSERS t left join  TBLPRODUCTS tp on t.userid=tp.userid 
left join TBLDAILYLOG tl on t.userid = tl.userid and tp.productkey = tl.productkey group by tp.ProductKey,t.UserID,t.UserName order by total;